# How to get values from a nested object

Tags: javascript, object, nested-object

let's say I have this object:

```
let obj = {
  name: "John",
  location: {
    country: "France",
    town: "Paris",
    street: { number: 23, name: "Napoleon" },
  },
};

let streetNumber = obj.location.street.number;
```

Is there a simpler method to get the street number without writing that big line of code **"obj.location.street.number"**? Imagine if I would have 10 levels in a nested object.
Actually I have a very very big object with unique keys and it takes too much time to write that chain until I get the desired value.

Comment: How do you expect to get the value without property access?

Comment: No there isn't. If the object is too big, create a better object structure or use more variables.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this, but I don't suggest you, it's better to go property by property, like you did.

```
function recursion(obj) {
  for (const prop in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      if (typeof obj[prop] == 'object') return recursion(obj[prop])
      if (prop == 'number') return obj[prop]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have to create a function for simplicity.

```js
const getStreetNumber = (obj) => obj["location"]["street"]["number"];
```